# setting type and length on composite-key property in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In hbm mappings I can

```
<composite-id>
   [..]
   <key-property name="someStringProperty" 
                 column="somefield" 
                 type="AnsiString" 
                 lenght="8"/>
</composite-id>
```

How do I do that (setting type and length) in Fluent?

Edit:
I posted this on [support.fluentnhibernate.org](http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/339-setting-type-and-length-on-composite-key-property). I included some modifications to support setting the type to e.g. AnsiString there.

Edit 2:
Today Paul Batum has added support for a textual type and a length in his dev-branch. (See [github](http://github.com/paulbatum/fluent-nhibernate/commit/26f7b11ca908f9f28512298e5dae69fb25051a0e) on the changes.)
This makes it possible to write

```
CompositeId()
  .KeyProperty(
       p => p.SomeProp, 
       k => k.ColumnName("someField").Type("AnsiString").Length(8))
```

Comment: I see .ColumnName() and .Type() but not .Length(). Using  Fluent NHibernate 1.1.1.694.

Comment: I guess it hasn't landed in trunk yet.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. There is no mention of this on the fluent wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you can't. You can only go as far as ...

```
CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Id1, "ID1")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Id2, "ID2");
```

There is no option for type or length.

But in version 1.1 there seems to be a possibility

```
CompositeId() 
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id1) 
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id2, kp => kp 
                .ColumnName("ID2") 
                .Type(typeof(string)));
```

Comment: But the fluent `Type(typeof(string))` still results in a nvarchar mapping, whereas the hbm `type="AnsiString"` results in a varchar mapping!? So there no charge at all?

Comment: Seems like it. Altough it looks like they could be adding a CustomType to it in the future. Who knows. You might want to start a discussion to add it to the API at http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/.

Comment: Ok. this answer is correct. It is currently impossible to set the length property on composite key parts and the only possible types to set are .net-types. See the edit on the question for a link to more information.

Answer (score 2):

I updated to 1.2 and am able to set the type of a key property to AnsiString

```
            CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.ViewDto, "type_id")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.FieldName, p =>
                                               {
                                                   p.ColumnName("field_name");
                                                   p.Type("AnsiString");
                                               });
```